# Small confusion about PhoneStateIntentReceiver

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

```
public class MyReceiver extends PhoneStateIntentReceiver {        
  @Override        
  public void onReceiveIntent(Context context, Intent intent) {  
    if (intent.action == Intent.CALL_ACTION) {         

    }
  }
}
```

Assume that notifyPhoneCallState has been called to enable MyReceiver to receive notifications about phone call states, in which case the code will get executed?

- when device receives an incoming call
- when outgoing call is initiated  on the device
- when the user presses the call button
- incoming phone call is terminated
- or will the code not be executed at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean `public static final String ACTION_CALL` instead of `CALL_ACTION`?

> Activity Action: **Perform a call to someone specified by the data.**
>
> Input: If nothing, an empty dialer is started; else getData() is URI of a phone number to be dialed or a tel: URI of an explicit phone number.
>
> Output: nothing.
>
> Note: there will be restrictions on which applications can initiate a call; most applications should use the ACTION_DIAL.
>
> Note: this Intent cannot be used to call emergency numbers. Applications can dial emergency numbers using ACTION_DIAL, however.

Comment: Why that answer is marked as answer? It's just a comment about typo in question that should be typed in comments box, not as answer at all